# Is there an equivalent of FullGraphics for Graphics3D?

Tags: graphics

For 2D graphics, there exists the function `FullGraphics` to turn the stuff Mathematica generates automatically on `Graphics` (like axes) into explicit graphics primitives. However that function doesn't work on `Graphics3D` objects. So is there some (possibly undocumented) function which does the same for 3 dimensional graphics?

Comment: I don't know, but I don't believe so.  The reason is that 2D and 3D can be mixed: `Graphics3D[Sphere[], Epilog -> {Circle[]}]`.

Comment: I've had this question since version three, actually...

Comment: @J.M. I think something was possible in v5 to project down 3D polygons to a `Graphics[]` and get a nice figure, but I'm not sure ...

Comment: Oh, I'm aware of `Shadow[]`, @Szabolcs; what I have been wondering is how does one get the ticks and boxes from a `Graphics3D[]` object. Among other things...

Comment: @J.M. It was not shadow but something undocumented that generated a 2D graphics object that looked like the 3D object from some viewpoint.  I might be wrong though.  And I see now that this is not what the question is asking about.

Comment: One of the complications with Graphics3D is that the axes can move to different edges when rotating the bounding box. And even when you fix `AxesEdge`, the tick marks will be projected on different sides of the bounding box depending on the orientation of the figure. You would lose that effect when you replace the axes and tick marks with lines.

Comment: @Szabolcs You weren't referring to Project[] from the same v5.1 ``Graphics`Graphics3D` `` package as Shadow[]?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No solution with 3D return, but you can "vectorize" 3D graphics by using the good ole `ImportString[ExportString[...]]` trick which results in a (large) 2D `Graphics`expression:

```
g = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

```
vectorized2D = ImportString[ExportString[g, "PDF"], "PDF"][[1]]
```

[image]

This is now  a `Graphics` expression that you can use to extract certain features:

```
Cases[vectorized2D, _JoinedCurve, Infinity] // Graphics
```

[image]

but finding the right patterns for the stuff you might want to work with could take some effort. Also you have to live with the fact that some appearances will change more or less dramatically.

Comment: Going through PDF has the effect that (at least in my test, on 8.0.0.0) the numbers are translated into curves as well. I've found that when going through EPS instead, the numbers are kept as text (but then, for some reason the polygons were very wrong).

Comment: This sure is something that is changing a lot behind the scenes from version to version. I hope that there will be some kind of useful convergence in versions to come (e.g. an extension of `FilledCurve` to 3D would be very, very useful and much in the spirit of the already existing 2D+3D graphics primitives).