# How to draw multiple coordinates on mathematica?

Tags: graphics

For example:

[image]

How can I draw such kinds of coordinates?

Thank you~

Comment: Properly combining `Translate[]` and `Rotate[]` ought to do the trick...

Comment: This question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1003/is-there-an-equivalent-of-fullgraphics-for-graphics3d makes me feel you won't get too lucky

Comment: @J.M. anything to add to that, such as example code?

Comment: As Heike says, the 3D axes and ticks aren't fixed and depend on the angle that you've rotated your graphics. With two sets of axes MMA wouldn't even know what to do when you try to rotate your graphics. However, if you don't want anything more from an axes than the set of 3 lines you drew, it's quite simple to do

Comment: If sam's expecting ticks on his coordinate systems, then I don't think he has a sporting chance. If sam can give the precise conversion formula between his two coordinate systems, I'm sure we can easily produce that diagram...

Comment: Do you mean the 2D projections of those coordinate systems as you've included, or 3D model?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You build this in Mathematica like you would do in any other descriptive language (you might want to use TikZ for this): step by step. Choosing nicer colors,adjusting the distances  etc. is left as an exercise to the reader.

```
cosy[labels_, labelstyle_] := Flatten@{
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}],
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}],
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}],
    labelstyle,
    Text[labels[[1]], {1.1, 0, 0}],
    Text[labels[[2]], {0, 1.1, 0}],
    Text[labels[[3]], {0, 0, 1.1}]
};
Graphics3D[{
    { (* Coordinate system 1 *)

   cosy[{"X", "Y", "Z"}, Darker@Orange],
        Darker@Orange,
        Text["World", {-.3, -.3, .5}]
    },
    { (* Coordinate system 2 *)

   Rotate[cosy[{"x", "y", "z"}, Blue], -30 \[Degree], {-1, 0, 1}]~
    Translate~{0, 0, -2}
    },

    { (* Connecting arrow *)
        Darker@Green,
        Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -2}}],
        Text["C(t)", {0, -.2, -1}]
    },

    { (* Red stuff *)
        Red,
        Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 3, -1}}],
        Arrow[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 3, -1}}],
        Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(world\)]\)", 
    1/2 {0, 3, -1} + {0, 0, .5}],
        Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(0\)]\)", 
    1/2 {0, 3, -1} + {0, 0, -1.5}],
        Text["p(t)", {0, 3, -1} + {0, .5, 0}]
    }
  }, Boxed -> False]
```

> [image]

Comment: Why the `Flatten` in `Graphics3D`? It actually makes it more complicated as the inner lists act as scoping constructs: directives within them do not affect the directives outside of them. So, you can remove both `Flatten` and the second `Black` and get the same result as `cosy` ensures that the color directive passed in does not affect anything after it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even know you could use scoping in graphics objects, thank you! Code modified.

Answer (score 4):

This is a variation on David's answer.

```
o = {0, 0, 0};

Clear[axis];
axis[p_, label_] := {Arrowheads[0.025], Arrow[{o, p}], Text[label, p]}

Clear[axes];
axes[labels_List, labelSize_, labelColor_] := 
 MapThread[axis, {IdentityMatrix[3], Style[#, labelSize, labelColor, Bold] & /@ labels}]

ct = 1. {0, 3, 3};
pt = {-0.5, -4, 2};

Graphics3D[{
 axes[{"\!\(\*StyleBox[\"Z\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"X\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"Y\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)"}, 17, Blend[{Orange, Yellow}]], 
 Translate[Rotate[axes[{"\!\(\*StyleBox[\"z\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"x\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"y\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)"}, 17, Darker@Blue], -35 Degree, {1, 1, 0}], ct], 
 Arrowheads[0.015], Darker@Green, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, ct}], 
 Text[Style["C(\!\(\*StyleBox[\"t\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\))", 14, Bold], Mean[{o, ct}], {-1, 1}], 
 Red, Arrow[{ct, pt}], Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(O\)]\)", 14, Bold], Mean[{ct, pt}], {-.5, -2}], 
 Arrow[{o, pt}], 
 Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[StyleBox[\"p\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"], \(World\)]\)", 14, Bold], Mean[{o, pt}], {1, 0}], 
 Text[Style["\!\(\*StyleBox[\"p\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)(\!\(\*StyleBox[\"t\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\))", 14, Bold], pt, {-.5, -1}], 
 Text[Style["\!\(\*StyleBox[\"O\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", 20, Bold, Darker@Blue], ct + .1 (pt - ct), {0, -5}]}, 
Boxed -> False, 
ViewVertical -> {0.37, 0.1, 2.1}, 
ViewPoint -> {1.7, 2.5, 1.6}]
```

[image: two-axes example]

The StyleBoxes appeared only because I formatted the fonts with italic and subscripts. The code looks cleaner in my notebook!

To choose values for the `ViewVertical` and `ViewPoint` options, I evaluated the expressions, then rotated the graphic to what I thought looked good, then evaluated `FullOptions[]` on the graphic, using values close what that output gave. Further refinement would involve tuning the angles and positions of the axes labels.