# How can I label the arrowhead?

Tags: plotting, labeling

I want to put a label in the three arrowheads on the top. I tryed with "VertexLabel" but I don't know how this command works.[image]

```
CampoB = 1;
AFLorentz = 1;
MovimentoX = 0 ;
ring[z_] := 
  Graphics3D[
   Rotate[Arrow@
     Table[{Cos[u] - MovimentoX, Sin[u], z}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi], 
       2 \[Pi]/30}], {{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}], Boxed -> False];

RingSet = Show[Table[myring[z], {z, -7, 1, 2}]];

FLorentz = 
  Arrow[{{0 + MovimentoX, 0, 8}, {AFLorentz + MovimentoX, 0, 8}}];

Cilindro = 
  Graphics3D[{{Red, Opacity[0.1], 
     Cylinder[{{0 + MovimentoX, 0, -1}, {0 + MovimentoX, 0, 7}}, 
      1]}, {Thickness[0.01], Arrowheads[{0, .03}], FLorentz, 
     Arrow[{{0 + MovimentoX, 0, 8}, {0 + MovimentoX, -0 - CampoB, 
        8}}], Arrow[{{0 + MovimentoX, 0, -1}, {0 + MovimentoX, 0, 
        10}}]}}];

Imagem = Show[Cilindro, RingSet, 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-3, 3}, {-1, 10}}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  ViewPoint -> {-2, -1.5, 1.7}]
```

The part of code wich is drawing the three arrows on the the top are:

"FLorentz = 
      Arrow[{{0 + MovimentoX, 0, 8}, {AFLorentz + MovimentoX, 0, 8}}];"

and inside "Cilindro =", "Arrow[{{0 + MovimentoX, 0, 8}, {0 + MovimentoX, -0 - CampoB, 
            8}}], Arrow[{{0 + MovimentoX, 0, -1}, {0 + MovimentoX, 0, 
            10}}]}}]"

Comment: Look up `Text[]`.

Comment: Have a look at [How to draw multiple coordinates on mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1183/how-to-draw-multiple-coordinates-on-mathematica)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you want these labels drawn? Do you want them to be 3D objects and rotate accordingly? Or you just need them always face the camera?

For the second case the `Text[]` is what you need (I replaced `myring` with `ring`):

```
Cilindro = 
  Graphics3D[{{Red, Opacity[0.1], 
     Cylinder[{{0 + MovimentoX, 0, -1}, {0 + MovimentoX, 0, 7}}, 
      1]}, {Thickness[0.01], Arrowheads[{0, .03}], FLorentz, 
     Text["X", {0.2 + AFLorentz + MovimentoX, 0, 8}], 
     Arrow[{{0 + MovimentoX, 0, 8}, {0 + MovimentoX, -0 - CampoB, 
        8}}], Text["Y", {MovimentoX, -0 - CampoB - 0.2, 8}], 
     Arrow[{{0 + MovimentoX, 0, -1}, {0 + MovimentoX, 0, 10}}], 
     Text["Z", {0, 0, 10.2}]}}];
```

[image]

For the first case you can actually construct labels (to be artistic?)

```
moveScale[pos_, scale_] := #*scale + pos &;
zLabel[pos_, size_] := 
  Tube[moveScale[pos, 
     size] /@ {{-1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, -1}, {1, 0, -1}}, 
   0.2*size];
xLabel[pos_, 
   size_] := {Tube[
    moveScale[pos, size] /@ {{-0.5, 0, 1}, {0.5, 0, -1}}, 0.2*size], 
   Tube[moveScale[pos, size] /@ {{0.5, 0, 1}, {-0.5, 0, -1}}, 
    0.2*size]};
yLabel[pos_, 
   size_] := {Tube[
    moveScale[pos, size] /@ {{-0.5, 0, 1}, {0.0, 0, 0}}, 0.2*size], 
   Tube[moveScale[pos, size] /@ {{0.5, 0, 1}, {-0.5, 0, -1}}, 
    0.2*size]};

Cilindro = 
  Graphics3D[{{Green, zLabel[{0.5, 0, 9.5}, 0.1]}, {Red, 
     xLabel[{0.2 + AFLorentz + MovimentoX, 0, 8}, 0.1]},
    {Blue, yLabel[{MovimentoX, -0 - CampoB - 0.2, 8}, 0.1]}, {Red, 
     Opacity[0.1], 
     Cylinder[{{0 + MovimentoX, 0, -1}, {0 + MovimentoX, 0, 7}}, 
      1]}, {Thickness[0.01], Arrowheads[{0, .03}], FLorentz, 
     Arrow[{{0 + MovimentoX, 0, 8}, {0 + MovimentoX, -0 - CampoB, 
        8}}], Arrow[{{0 + MovimentoX, 0, -1}, {0 + MovimentoX, 0, 
        10}}]}}];

Imagem = Show[Cilindro, RingSet, 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-3, 3}, {-1, 10}}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  ViewPoint -> {-2, -1.5, 1.7}]
```

Now your "labels" will rotate accordingly.
[image]