# Number of edges to each polygon of a graph constructed from an image

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image-processing

I have an image which looks like

[image]

from [How to convert an image to a graph and get the positions of the edges?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8935/how-to-convert-an-image-to-a-graph-and-get-the-positions-of-the-edges)

which by using `MorphologicalGraph` becomes a graph that is a collections of polygons:

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/cET4A.png"];
g = MorphologicalGraph[i, 
     EdgeStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[.5], Thickness[.01]],
     GraphStyle -> "ThickEdge"];
Show[ColorNegate@Dilation[i, 1], g]
```

I am wondering if, for each polygon, it is possible to extract the number of edges?

Answer (score 4):

There are some stray lines in the image which may be difficult to handle.  You can remove these using `Pruning`.  Use `MorphologicalGraph` after this.  Now your problem is reduced to finding the faces of the planar graph you obtained.  You'll find complete code for that in the answer to this question:

- [Finding face vertices from the face adjacency graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18514/12)

Answer (score 2):

You have a few lines pointing out here and there, suggesting that it's actually only lines, not polygons.

```
coords = VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions[g, VertexCoordinates];
con = (ArrayRules@AdjacencyMatrix[g])[[1 ;; -2, 1]];
Graphics@GraphicsComplex[coords, Line[Union[Sort /@ con]]]
```

[image: lines]

If you right click your original graph and *Convert to Graphics* that is also composed of `Line`s and a bit of styling.